# MAGENTO 1.5: Products that generate printable PDF's

Tags: php, oop, magento, zend-framework, zend-pdf

- We create credentials from PDF's.
- The background image is already printed onto a piece of paper (A4: Landscape)
- From inputs in our products (Custom Options > Name and Date) and an incrementing credential number which is stored in our database; we overlay these on our A4 papers at specific coordinates to print a final product ourselves.

We typically sell around 400 ~ 900 of these a day, so we would need a combined PDF sheet that
generates/adds all these to single printable document. How these are segregated from yesterdays orders
or todays orders, or orders after printing todays orders doesn't matter. It could be by LAST credential
number, or by date/time cut-off, or whatever. It's negligable as long as there is not duplicates.

Things I would like to see is the ability for the user to preview their credential prior to submission
(JQuery would most likely fit the bill, I envisioned updating the preview image from the input fields),
the ability to use a filter array or list (could be a flatfile?) so we can remove banned words, and lastly
so we can correct mistakes even the the user makes them, a way to edit the PDF's, either direclty through
a tool.

I've been looking around for a plugin or module for the last week that I could at least get a starting
point on to do this. If not this is something that will need to be created from scratch. I looked at web
to print by Zetaprints briefly but there is not only a complicated install process, but also a pay per use
of about a $1.70 that would quickly eat into our profit margins.

**What we do now**
This is the old version that we used with OSCommerce that will need to be replaced by a Magento equivalent.

Old Version with Edit Capabilities: http://pastebin.com/pafG0RLZ

New Version without Editing: http://pastebin.com/b4a3kim1

Here is the physical code of the new version that would need some kind of integration.

```
    case "Ordination Credentials":

        // hack -jd
        include ('class.ezpdf.php'); 
        $pdf =& new Cezpdf('LETTER','landscape'); 
        $pdf->selectFont('./fonts/mtcorsva.afm'); 
        $pdf->ezSetMargins(30,1,30,1);

            extract($_GET); 

        $query = "
                SELECT  o.date_purchased, 
                        fd.template_fn, 
                        o.customers_name, 
                        op.orders_id, 
                        opa.orders_products_id, 
                        products_name, 
                        op.products_quantity, 
                        field_name, 
                        products_options_values

                FROM orders_products AS op
                JOIN orders AS o ON o.orders_id                     = op.orders_id
                JOIN fulfillment_doc_products AS fdp ON fdp.product_id          = op.products_id
                JOIN fulfillment_docs AS fd ON fd.doc_id                = fdp.doc_id
                JOIN orders_products_attributes AS opa ON opa.orders_products_id    = op.orders_products_id

                RIGHT JOIN fulfillment_doc_fields AS fdf ON fdf.products_options_name   = opa.products_options

                    AND fdf.doc_products_id                                             = fdp.doc_products_id

                WHERE op.orders_id
                BETWEEN $in

                    AND $out
                    AND fd.doc_id                                                       = $doc_id

                ORDER BY o.orders_id, products_name, opa.orders_products_id, field_name, products_options_values";

            $result = mysql_query(trim($query)) or die("Broke the interwebs.");
            while ($query_data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                //Standard db output filtering and processing into multi-dimensional array as seen above                
                $creds[$query_data['orders_products_id']][$query_data['field_name']]    = sanitize_db_output($query_data['products_options_values']);
                $creds[$query_data['orders_products_id']]['order_number']       = $query_data['orders_id'];
                $creds[$query_data['orders_products_id']]['products_quantity']      = $query_data['products_quantity'];

            }

                $started = false;

            foreach( $creds as $opt ) {
                if($started) { $pdf->ezNewPage(); } //create new page

                    $started = true;
                    $name = ucwords(strtolower($opt['name']));
                
                    foreach (array('-', '\'',' Mc') as $delimiter) {
                        if (strpos($name, $delimiter) == true) {
                            $name = implode($delimiter, array_map('ucfirst', explode($delimiter, $name)));
                        }
                    }

                //all caps
                foreach (array('Ii', 'Iii') as $delimiter) {
                    if (strpos($name, $delimiter) == true) {
                        $name = implode($delimiter, array_map('strtoupper', explode($delimiter, $name)));
                  }
                }

                if(strpos($name, ',') !== false) { 
                    foreach (array(', Jr', ', Sr') as $delimiter) {
                        if (strpos($name, $delimiter) == false) {
                            $name=implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(',', $name)));
                        }
                    }
                }

                    $day = $opt["date-day"];

                if (0<>$day) {
                    if (in_array($day% 100, range(11,13))) {
                        $day .= 'th';
                    } else {
                        switch ( $day % 10 ) {
                            case 1:  $day .= 'st'; break;
                            case 2:  $day .= 'nd'; break;
                            case 3:  $day .= 'rd'; break;
                            default: $day .= 'th'; break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                    $month  = $opt["date-month"];
                    $year   = $opt["date-year"];
                    $ordid  = $opt["order_number"];

                //create date
                if (!isset($yname)) { $yname = "370"; }
                if (!isset($ydate)) { $ydate = "289"; }

                    $pdf->ezSetY($yname);   $pdf->ezText($name,28,array('left'=>-35, 'justification'=>'center'));
                    $pdf->ezSetY($ydate);   $pdf->ezText($day,17,array('left'=>-220, 'justification'=>'center'));
                    $pdf->ezSetY($ydate);   $pdf->ezText($month,17,array('left'=>40, 'justification'=>'center'));
                    $pdf->ezSetY($ydate);   $pdf->ezText($year,17,array('left'=>375, 'justification'=>'center'));
                    $pdf->ezSetY(96);       $pdf->ezText($ordid,12,array('left'=>505, 'justification'=>'center'));
            }

            $pdfcode = $pdf->output(); 
            $file = './tmp/PDF_ordinations.pdf';

            if (file_exists($fname)) { unlink($fname); }    //start with new file
            if (!file_exists($dir)) { mkdir ($dir,0777); }  //dir create if not there

                $fname = $file;
                $fp = fopen($fname,'w'); 

            fwrite($fp,$pdfcode); 
            fclose($fp); 

        header('Location:'.$fname);

    break;
```

Comment: We really need a Magento Area in the Stack Exchange...

Comment: I completely agree. They get passed over here just as much as in the Magento forum....

Comment: sorry, read the FAQ and keep this forum clean for theoretical type of questions and ask programming questions

Comment: @Anton this isn't theoretical, I've created this module outside of Zend already for processing, integrating it or something similar would be the real thing. I'll post code to show that it can and has been done.

Comment: well your actual question is not related to programming at all :( "Can anyone recommend something that might work, or a starting point to take? If users feel that this can be done by them and their company I would entertain contracting this out?" as for a developer it is just iteration over order objects and sending the output do pdf template. Orders are stored in sales_flat_order table , go ahead and try that. Sadly this is not a place for asking quotes for the job.

Comment: I will look in sales_flat_order and see if I can get some code working, Thank you Anton.

Comment: Every PDF is printable. Portability which includes printability is one of the main reasons why we have PDF. I don't really get your question. You want to generate PDF? If so, check out princeXML, it's great!

Comment: Hey Markus, we actually are trying to print a **specialized** pdf, one that is in landscape mode with order number, name and date in a specific format.